# How to retrieve pandas dataframe rows surrounding rows with a True boolean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Suppose I have a df of the following format:

[image]

Assumed line 198 would be True for rot_mismatch, what would be the best way to retrieve the True line (easy) and the line above and below (unsolved)?

I have multiple lines with a True boolean and would like to automatically create a dataframe for closer investigation, always including the True line and its surrounding lines.

Thanks!

Edit for clarification:

exemplary input:

| id | name | Bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | False |
| 2 | Danny | True |
| 3 | Elle | False |
| 4 | Rob | False |
| 5 | Dan | False |
| 6 | Holger | True |
| 7 | Mat | True |
| 8 | Derrick | False |
| 9 | Lisa | False |

desired output:

| id | name | Bool |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | False |
| 2 | Danny | True |
| 3 | Elle | False |
| 5 | Dan | False |
| 6 | Holger | True |
| 7 | Mat | True |
| 8 | Derrick | False |

Comment: could you include an input we could copy and paste along with the expected output?

Comment: Added it, sorry for confusion. I hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
  col1  rot_mismatch
0    A         False
1    B          True
2    C         False
3    D         False
4    E         False
5    F         False
6    G          True
7    H          True
```

to get the N rows before/after any True, you can use a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) operation to compute a mask for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 1
mask = (df['rot_mismatch']
        .rolling(2*N+1, center=True, min_periods=1)
        .max().astype(bool)
       )
df2 = df.loc[mask]
```

output:

```
# N = 1
  col1  rot_mismatch
0    A         False
1    B          True
2    C         False
5    F         False
6    G          True
7    H          True

# N = 0
  col1  rot_mismatch
1    B          True
6    G          True
7    H          True

# N = 2
  col1  rot_mismatch
0    A         False
1    B          True
2    C         False
3    D         False
4    E         False
5    F         False
6    G          True
7    H          True
```

Comment: This looks very promising, will try it later and respond whether it worked. Thank you! Small thing: in "# N = 3", I assume you meant to write "# N = 1", right?

Comment: @Paul1911 yes N=1 (2*N+1 = 3) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `shift`:

```
>>> df[df["rot_mismatch"]|df["rot_mismatch"].shift()|df["rot_mismatch"].shift(-1)]
        dep_ap_sched     arr_ap_sched  rot_mismatch
120      East Carmen  South Nathaniel         False
198  South Nathaniel      East Carmen          True
289      East Carmen       Joneshaven         False
```

Output for amended example:

```
>>> df[df["Bool"]|df["Bool"].shift()|df["Bool"].shift(-1)]
   id     name   Bool
0   1      Sta  False
1   2    Danny   True
2   3     Elle  False
4   5      Dan  False
5   6   Holger   True
6   7      Mat   True
7   8  Derrick  False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess that would create duplicate rows in the case two succeeding True values, right (ID6&7 would be dupes then)?

Comment: @Paul1911 - No it doesn't. Added the output for your new example as well. Matches your expected output.

Comment: Interesting, then that's the even more elegant solution.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want ?

```
df_true=df.loc[df['rot_mismatch']=='True',:]
df_false=df.loc[df['rot_mismatch']=='False',:]
```

Comment: Not exactly, but thanks for thinking into it, I got a working solution :)